# IEEEtran and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, indexing, ieeetran

I am trying to figure out how to use `IEEEtran` with `glossaries` without running into errors during the compilation with (pdf)latex.

Here is my MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{elite}{name={elite},description={This is an elite glossary}}
\newglossaryentry{master}{name={master},description={This is a master glossary}}

\begin{document}

Test of first glossary entry: \gls{elite}
Test of second glossary entry: \gls{master}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The code above runs just fine when using `article` as the document class or when using only one entry, which leads me to believe that this error has to do with `IEEEtran`.

Below is the error I get from (pdf)latex:

```
(./doc.gls
! Undefined control sequence.
\glsgroupskip ...glsnogroupskip \else \indexspace
                                                 \fi
1.5 ...r[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
```

Everything works in both my original file and the MWE when I exclude the `\printglossaries`.

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, the `IEEEtran` class doesn't provide a definition for `\indexspace` so you need to provide it, using, for example, the definition used by `article.cls`:

```
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
```

A complete example:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{elite}{name={elite},description={This is an elite glossary}}
\newglossaryentry{master}{name={master},description={This is a master glossary}}

\begin{document}

Test of first glossary entry: \gls{elite}
Test of second glossary entry: \gls{master}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]